# Looking for GIS topographic data of Bogota, Colombia, with elevation contour lines

Tags: geospatial, south-america

I'm looking for the GIS data to create a topographic map of Bogota, Colombia; specifically, we want to get the elevation contour lines, and export that layer to CAD.

If anyone knows of any free places to find this data, we would love to hear it! I've been looking through some of the sources here http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/ - but I'm not very familiar with that huge list. If anyone knows of a specific link in there that would be best to investigate, please let us know.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can create contours using DEM data. If you go to   https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ you will be able to get free DEM data from the Aster Global DEM Mission.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try and contact universities over there and check to see if they have any GIS data they might have. They can be a geography department or geology or Engineering .. Since they might be easy to find in local area there... I am not sure for online that you can find out there..